# Android application only for 10" tablets not latest phones

Tags: android, android-screen-support

How can I limit my app to be only for tablets? E.g. how to support Galaxy Tab but not Galaxy SIII ? Both have the same resolution and density.

Will this code be sufficient:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

After reading docs again, is having below section:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />        
</compatible-screens>
```

makes the whole setup a correct one?

Comment: can refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.  n this code 'll work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make above provisions in manifest

Go to Console (Developer's console)

```
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
```

- Select your app from App listing.
- Go to APK Tab (left side in a page)

You will be able to see 'See supported devices' hyperlink
Open it,

You can see list of supported devices there. Manually exclude devices which you do not want.