# restrict android app installation to Android phones

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to to restrict an Android app installation to phones only? either via code/play store?
I don't want my app to be installed on tablets

Comment: You can check in code for device type, if tablet show a message and exit

Comment: See this answer. It may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851986/android-application-only-for-10-tablets-not-latest-phones

Comment: @Warlock, can you tell me how to check the device type?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to add restrictions to your manifest.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).

Comment: Thanks. I inlcuded this. But nothing is stopping the user from taking the apk and installing it on the tablet . So is there a way to exit the app nicely instead of crashing?

Comment: You can always programatically measure the device width, height and screen density. Then try to determine that the device is actually a tablet and exit nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any elegant way to do it. but this might help you out. basically it eliminates big screens.

```
<manifest>
....    
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"
                      android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
    <application>
    ......
    </application>
<manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...To do so, you can enable filtering by external services such as Google
>   Play by adding elements to your manifest file that specify the screen
>   configurations your application supports.

Source : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps.